# Inverse of particular matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I have a $ n \times n $ matrix with the following form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a^n+b^n & C_{n,1} \; a b^{n-1} & \cdots & C_{n,n-1} \; a^{n-1} b \\
C_{n,n-1} \; a^{n-1} b & a^n + b^n & \cdots & C_{n,n-2} a^{n-2} b^2\\
\vdots & \ddots & & \vdots\\
C_{n,1} \; a^1 b^{n-1} & C_{n,2} \; a^2 b^{n-2} & \cdots & a^n + b^n 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some real numbers $ a $ and $ b $ with $ a \neq b $, and where $ C_{n,k} $ is the binomial coefficient. (In other words the matrix elements are terms in $ (a+b)^n $, and each row/column is a shift of the previous row/column). I am trying to find an expression for the inverse, and although I can get bits and pieces, I am just not able to get the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Perhaps it's also worth mentioning that the matrix above is the $ n$th power of the $ n \times n $ matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & \cdots & b \\ b & a & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & b & a
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what the missing entries are.  Can you give an explicit formula for $a_{ij}$ or at least give the $n = 3$ case explicitly?

Comment: Is each row (resp., column) a cyclic shift of the previous row (resp., column)?

Comment: For clarity: the matrix is a circulant matrix with first row given by the terms of the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^n$, except that the final term $b^n$ is taken together with the first term.

Comment: Yes each row is a cyclic shift. I could give an explicit formula, but I am sure it would not be very enlightening. Marc van Leeuwen's description is correct (and clearer, thanks Marc!).

Answer (score 0):

*Partial answer*

Using the fact that the rows/columns are cyclic shifts of previous rows, you can show the following:

For odd $n$, I see that the determinant is
$$\left(b+a\right)^n\,\left(b^{n-1}-a\,b^{n-2}+a^2\,b^{n-3}\cdots+a^{n-1}\right)^n$$

For even $n$ the result is similar but further factorization is possible
$$\left(b-a\right)^n\,\left(b+a\right)^n\,\cdots $$

There seems to be no simple pattern for the inverse.

**Edited based on OP's update**

From OP's remark
$$
M = Q^n$$
where $Q$ is as shown in OP's question.

Now $Q$ is also cyclic and the first row of $Q$ is
$$
\text{det}(Q) Q^{-1} =\pmatrix{a^n &(-b)^n& a (-b)^{n-1} &a^2 (-b)^{n-2} &\cdots &  a^{n-1} (-b) \\
- a^{n-1} b & a^n & (-b)^n & a (-b)^{n-1} &a^2 (-b)^{n-2} &\cdots\\
\cdots}$$

Not sure how much this helps.

BTW, your formulas will become *slightly* more manageable if you use (-b) instead of $b$.

Comment: I think the determinant is easily computed, see the edit above. It's really the inverse that is hurting me.

Comment: me too :) I don't see any pattern at all.